# help with expect script, run cat on remote comp and get output of it to the variable

Tags: bash, expect, cat

I have a bash+expect script which has to connect via ssh to the remote comp, read the file there, find specific line with the "hostname" (like "hostname aaaa1111") and store this hostname into the variable to be used after while. How can i get the value of the "hostname" parameter? I thought that line content will be in $expect_out(buffer) variable (so i can scan it and analyze), but it's not. My script is:

```
    #!/bin/bash        
    ----bash part----
    /usr/bin/expect << ENDOFEXPECT
    spawn bash -c "ssh root@$IP"  
    expect "password:"
    send "xxxx\r"
    expect ":~#"
    send "cat /etc/rc.d/rc.local |grep hostname \n"
    expect ":~#"
    set line $expect_out(buffer)
    puts "line = $line, expect_out(buffer) = $expect_out(buffer)"
    ...more script...
    ENDOFEXPECT
```

Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect there is an example:

```
    # Send the prebuilt command, and then wait for another shell prompt.
    send "$my_command\r"
    expect "%"
    # Capture the results of the command into a variable. This can be displayed, or written to disk.
    set results $expect_out(buffer)
```

seems that it doesn't work in this case, or what's wrong with the script?

Comment: [Michael is right](http://serverfault.com/questions/300238/help-with-expect-script-run-cat-on-remote-comp-and-get-output-of-it-to-the-varia/300246#300246). However, the answer to the expect question is: you need `\r` instead of `\n` in your `send` command.

Comment: I need to use password identification in this script (for some reasons), and expect looks just right for this. And i've tried \r and \n in send command, anyway when i try to see line variable, i see only this:
        line = , expect_out(buffer) = (buffer)
        variable is not assigned by any conversion specifiers
            while executing ...
What is the right way to get the line from the file into the variable?

Comment: Or it might be a way to open and read and scan the file on the remote comp using expect itself, without "send"?

Comment: No, because expect is running on your local machine, so you have to "send" the commands to the ssh process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, your heredoc acts like a double quoted string, so the `$expect_out` variable is being substituted by the shell before `expect` starts. You need to ensure your heredoc is not being touched by the shell. Therefore, any shell variables need to be fetched in a different way. Here, I'm assuming `IP` is a shell variable, and I'm passing it through the environment.

```
export IP
/usr/bin/expect << 'ENDOFEXPECT'
  set prompt ":~#"
  spawn ssh root@$env(IP)  
  expect "password:"
  send "xxxx\r"
  expect $prompt
  send "grep hostname /etc/rc.d/rc.local \n"
  expect $prompt
  set line $expect_out(buffer)
  ...more script...
ENDOFEXPECT
```

Comment: Thanks glenn. IP is a variable defined in the "bash part", it's an argument to the script actually. I re-wrote this part, but still output is:
`expect_out = (buffer)
grep hostname /etc/rc.d/rc.local 
hostname aaa1111
:~#
line = , expect_out(buffer) = (buffer)` etc

Comment: Ok, even if i change it so that all expect part is now a separate script (called by the bash script), still i can't get what i want. The script goes like this:
`send "grep hostname /etc/rc.d/rc.local \r"
 expect $prt
 set line $expect_out(buffer)
 puts "line = $line, expect_out(buffer)=$expect_out(buffer), expect_out(0,string)=$expect_out(0,string)"`, and the output (sirprisingly to me) is now: `expect_out(buffer)= grep hostname /etc/rc.d/rc.local`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using expect for this?

```
ssh -i ssh_private_key root@${IP} "grep -E -o 'hostname.*$' /etc/rc.d/rc.local"
```

Comment: and if you want the output in a variable, `theoutput=$(allthatstuff)`

Comment: I need to use password identification in this script (for some reasons), and can't exchange keys for this script